# Rebol calc-workdays not working on Red

Tags: rebol, red

I trying to execute this script https://www.mail-archive.com/rebol-bounce@rebol.com/msg01222.html in Red but I can't see why I got

> calc-workdays now/date 3-feb-2007 [1-feb-2007]
>
> *** Script Error: > operator is missing an argument
>
> *** Where: do
>
> *** Stack: print calc-workdays

```
    found?: func [
        "Returns TRUE if value is not NONE."
        value
    ][
        not none? :value
    ]

    calc-workdays: func [
        "Return number of workdays between two dates, excluding holidays"
        date1 [date!] "Start date"
        date2 [date!] "End date"
        holidays [block!] "Block of dates to exclude (holidays, etc.)"
        /non "Return number of non-work days (weekend + holidays) between 2 dates"
        /local days day1 day2 diff param
    ][
        days: copy []
        set [day1 day2] sort reduce [date1 date2]
        diff: day2 - day1
        param: pick [[> 5 union][< 6 exclude]] either found? non [1][2]
        loop diff [
            day1: day1 + 1
            if do param/1 day1/weekday param/2 [append days day1]
        ]
        return length? do param/3 days holidays
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebol2 seems to allow you to pass a WORD! to DO, and evaluate it.  If the word happens to be a variable holding an ANY-FUNCTION!, it will be run...and if it's an infix "OP!" then it will be run as if it were *not* infix.

```
>> do quote > 1 2
== false

>> do quote < 1 2
== true
```

Red sort of does this also, but DO is not variadic.  It can run 0 arity functions only:

```
>> foo: does [print "hi"]

>> do quote foo
hi    

>> bar: func [x] [print x]

>> do quote bar "hi"
*** Script Error: bar is missing its x argument
```

The script in question was attempting to use this feature.  But it could be done with ordinary COMPOSE or REDUCE.  So change:

```
if do param/1 day1/weekday param/2 [append days day1]
```

To:

```
if do reduce [day1/weekday param/1 param/2] [append days day1]
```

That will build a block of code where the `>` or `<` operator is in the middle, and execute it normally without relying on this WORD!-dispatch or infix-dropping behavior of DO.

Similarly, change:

```
return length? do param/3 days holidays
```

To:

```
return length? do reduce [param/3 days holidays]
```

With those changes, and removing the `found?` (it's not necessary) then it appears to work.

Comment: Note: There is a [construct called EVAL](https://forum.rebol.info/t/meet-the-eval-native/311) in Rebol3/Ren-C which lets you accomplish what DO was doing...except you would need to use GET-WORD! to extract the function from the word, e.g. `eval :param/1 day1/weekday param/2`.  The DO primitive, like Red's, only accepts 0-arity functions.